# Can't log in to after deploying to heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have a Django app that uses Wagtail and I'm trying to set up Django's authentication to work in Heroku.

Although I can create a super user via `heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser`, when I try to log in to the app via Heroku, I just get a password authentication error. The same procedure works locally.

If anyone has any ideas or has come across this before, I can provide more details if this problem sounds familiar.

Comment: What database are you using? Do you see your user in the database?

Comment: Why don't you acess django admin and create a user. `yoururl.com/admin`

Comment: @Chris It's a Postgres database, and all settings are correct there.  I've run createsuperuser (on Heroku) for a user called admin.  If I run it again, it DOES pick up the user, therefore the user 'admin' has been created, and exists in the Heroku instance.

Comment: @HellaSpace, I can't access the admin because the it's not accepting the password for any super user

Answer (score 0):

Solved it... Password hashers was not set in "settings.py"...

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher',
]
```

Comment: Ugh, no, _please_ don't use MD5 for password hashing. It's almost as bad as storing plain text passwords. It's not even a little bit secure. [The default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/passwords/#how-django-stores-passwords) should be just fine (which means you don't need it to set it in `settings.py`). **If you have to manually configure Django to use MD5 before you can log in, something else is _horribly_ broken.**

Comment: This is default in Wagtail from what I can see?  If this isn't in settings.py, then log in only works locally, and doesn't work on Heroku.

Comment: That would indicate gross incompetence. Any product that enforces MD5 hashing on its users in 2019 should be immediately thrown in the trash, reported, and viewed with equal parts mockery, suspicion, and horror. Thankfully, [it doesn't look like Wagtail does that](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/project_template/project_name/settings/base.py).

Comment: Interesting that you point that out - though I'm really sure I didn't add that to my 'settings/dev.py' and that it was there already when I started my project. I'll look more at this later because I'm sure I've seen it before in other example projects

Comment: Are you using a very old version?

Comment: Version 2.6 - which I don't think is too old.